# Compare dynamic number of strings inside a dictionary, storing the best match as a new key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, representing a certain ID along with an address. I'm trying to use the jaro distance algorithm to have the distance between them all (compare the first with all, the second with them all (except the first), and so on).

```
address_dict = [
    {'SiteID': 123, 'Address': '350- Maxwell Rd'},
    {'SiteID': 124, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Rd Ste 500'},
    {'SiteID': 125, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Road'},
    {'SiteID': 126, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Road 500'}
]
```

What I plan to have, is a dictionary that looks like this. SiteID 124 has a greater length and verbosity, so I may use it as the official one, instead of the address in each of the IDs we have.

```
address_dict = [
    {'SiteID': 123, 'Address': '350- Maxwell Rd', 'reference_id': 124},
    {'SiteID': 124, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Rd Ste 500', 'reference_id': 124},
    {'SiteID': 125, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Road', 'reference_id': 124},
    {'SiteID': 126, 'Address': '350 Maxwell Road 500', 'reference_id': 124}
]
```

What is says is: "considering the all the records all similar (depends on the threshold), I'll keep for all those IDs the records with the greater amount of information - or length".
The way I compare those two strings is pretty simple, actually: `jellyfish.jaro_distance(str_1, str_2)`.

So far, I was trying to build something like this, but it is incomplete. I could not figure out how to make this logic work, but I think it's cool to post what I have so far, so no one has to tell the full code.

```
counter = 0
for item in address_dict:
    
    ## Can't figure out how to loop over the record one with two, three and four
    similarity = jellyfish.jaro_distance(item['Address'], address_dict[])
    
    ## Get the record with the greater length
    
    
    ## Find the similarity and maps to the reference ID
    if similarity > 0.8:
        address_dict[counter]['reference_id'] = item['SiteID']
    
    counter+=1
```

I added some comments that I cannot figure out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with the help of [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) class from Python standard library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module:

```py
def similar(a, b):
    """Get similarity ratio between a and b.

    Args:
        a: value.
        b: other value.

    Returns:
        Similatity ratio.

    """
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"SiteID": 123, "Address": "350- Maxwell Rd"},
        {"SiteID": 124, "Address": "350 Maxwell Rd Ste 500"},
        {"SiteID": 125, "Address": "350 Maxwell Road"},
        {"SiteID": 126, "Address": "350 Maxwell Road 500"},
    ]
)
```

```py
# Add ratios as new column
df = df.assign(
    Match=df["Address"].map(
        lambda x: max(
            [similar(x, max(df["Address"], key=len))],
            key=lambda x: x if x != 1 else 0,
        )
    )
)

# Add reference_id if ratio > 0.7
df["reference_id"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[df["Match"] == 1, "SiteID"] if x["Match"] >= 0.7 else x["SiteID"],
    axis=1,
)

# Cleanup
df = df.drop(columns="Match")
```

```py
new_adsress_dict = df.to_dict(orient="records")

print(new_address_dict)
# Output
[
    {"SiteID": 123, "Address": "350- Maxwell Rd", "reference_id": 124},
    {"SiteID": 124, "Address": "350 Maxwell Rd Ste 500", "reference_id": 124},
    {"SiteID": 125, "Address": "350 Maxwell Road", "reference_id": 124},
    {"SiteID": 126, "Address": "350 Maxwell Road 500", "reference_id": 124},
]
```